# JSON.net Compact Framework Parsing ISO8601 dates

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, json.net

I am using JSON.net for Compact Framework - version 3.5r8. The referenced file is:  `Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll`.

If I have a JSON object with a date/time in ISO 8601 format, such as:

```
{
   "name": "TestObject",
   "timestamp": "2017-08-04T13:39:16+01:00"
}
```

And I de-serialize this using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(response)`,  C# parses the timestamp property to a DateTime as expected, however the time is parsed at 05:39AM so there is clearly a time zone issue in play causing the parsing to be out by 8 hours from UTC.

I appreciate the "full" / latest versions of JSON.net do have options we can pass by way of `JsonSerializerSettings` to alter the date time zone handling but none of these seem to be available with JSON.net Compact.

How can I cause the time stamp to be parsed in UTC as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set timezone.

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(response, new JsonSerializerSettings
           {
               DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
           });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as mentioned, there is no DateTimeZoneHandling options exposed in this version of JSON.net.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the only properties available in that namespace are here: http://imgur.com/a/RiqAy